# Linear algebra vs homological algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, exact-sequence

In linear algebra my book show the **five lemma**.
In wikipedia I noticed connection with the 9-lemma (=? 3x3 lemma), the snake lemma a.s.o.

> In the wikipedia page this lemma are described as being part of ??homological algebra??.
> Are all this lemmas also valid for linear algebra? (that is, could I take them as exercises?)

Comment: Given a field $\Bbb F$, the category $\Bbb F$-Vec of $\Bbb F$-vector spaces is an abelian category, so the lemmas hold there as well. They could be used as exercises, I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, algebra is algebra. It's often generalised to more general settings (modules etc.) but it's certainly valid in vector spaces and so in a linear algebra setting.  It's all part of modern algebra, basically.